# GWT table widget to display a large number of similar widgets

Tags: gwt

I need to display a big amount(1000+) of similar widgets (each widget
contains photo + descrption - about 400*400 px total) in a table -
say, 10 rows and 2 columns per page. I don't need option to select,
drag, highlight or do smth else with these widgets - just display
them.

It seems that FlexTable doesn't support paging. CellTable does, but it
seems to be too complicated and best suited for displaying different
data in different columns while I need just to place similar widgets
in each cell.

So, I'm a bit confused about what table to use and need some help
about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Celltable and family are definitely the way to go. From the docs :

> Cell widgets (data presentation widgets) are high-performance,
>   lightweight widgets composed of Cells for displaying data. Examples
>   are lists, tables, trees and browsers. These widgets are designed to
>   handle and display very large sets of data quickly.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets

And they support server side paging...

Your case from what I read.